# Populate database with resulting dict from for loop - psycopg2

Tags: python, json, postgresql, python-requests, psycopg2

I have this simple test routine to insert some data into my db:

```
import psycopg2

    try:
       connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="mypassword",
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="myjson_db")
       cursor = connection.cursor()

       postgres_insert_query = """ INSERT INTO myjson_db (LENGTH, WAREHOUSE, COST) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"""
       record_to_insert = (1.600, 2.0, 50000000)
       cursor.execute(postgres_insert_query, record_to_insert)
       connection.commit()
       count = cursor.rowcount
       print (count, "Record inserted successfully into myjson table")
    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error :
        if(connection):
            print("Failed to insert record into myjson table", error)
    finally:
        if(connection):
            cursor.close()
            connection.close()
            print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

This actually works, but, I'm confused, since, what I actually need, is to insert the result of an API into it (It is a `json`, yes, but I've managed to extract the needed data from it)

For example, this is my script for the API:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://url/api/object/")
data = response.json()
for object in data['results']:
    print(object['length'])

while data['next'] is not None:
    response = requests.get(data['next'])
    data = response.json()
    for object in data['results']:
        print(object['warehouse'])
```

So, this script, connects to the api, reads the paginated json response, and I loop on that response, to print a specific "field" that I want.

Now, how can I store this result into my postgres db tables?

Is there an "on the fly" way to integrate the requests script with a psycopg2 routine? Sort of "printing" like I'm doing but directly to the db?

Or should I approach this with a different mindset?

Mind that I can't use the `json` postgres fields, I do have some specified rows for this table, like `warehouse` or `length`.

Is there any similar example You could provide?

Comment: you are combining values `LENGTH, WAREHOUSE, COST` when making query, but you're obtaining them in different loops. Combine the needed dataset beforehand

Comment: But I mean, I can print that, with the right combination, the point is, that I can't find a way around to integrate this script into the postgres query. Also, this is a paginated API, I had to do this, this way, or I could just get the first page results.

Comment: Could you use  `cursor.executemany` to insert a list of collected records with one `INSERT` statement?

Comment: I will give it a try